# nginx auth_request error handling (unset error_page?)

Tags: nginx, auth-request

When using nginx `auth_request`, only 4 return codes are accepted: `2xx`, `401`, `403` and `500`. Handling these requires setting `error_page`. This is fine for `auth_request`, but all downstream apps returning these codes will end up using the same `error_page` handling.

*Example*:

```
location /test {
  auth_request /foo;
  error_page 500 /its-broke.html;
  proxy_pass http://bar;
}
```

If `auth_request` to `/foo` returns `500`, the its-broke.html is shown. This is the behavior I want. However, if `bar` returns `500` its-broke.html is also shown. I don't want this. Instead, I want `bar`'s `500` *error* response to be transmitted through to the browser.

`auth_request` will catch any `5xx` and handle it as `500`, so I can't just have `foo` return `520`. That results in the following error and `500` is returned anyway:

```
auth request unexpected status: 520 while sending to client
```

Any ideas for getting around this? I can't find a way to un-set error_page before the proxy pass either.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with some effort though

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {

    server {

        listen 80;

        location @autherror {

            return 500 "Auth returned 500";
        }

        location @proxy_api {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }

        location / {

            location /test {

                auth_request /auth;
                error_page 500 = @autherror;
                try_files dummy_non_existing_url = @proxy_api;
            }

        }
        location /auth {

            return 200 "auth passed";
        }

    }

    server {

        listen 8081;
        location / {
            return 200 "You came to $uri";
        }
        location /test2 {
            return 500 "Error from API";
        }
    }
}
```

Result from the API test is

```
$ curl localhost/test
You came to /test

$ curl localhost/test2
Error from API
```

Now if I change `return 200 "auth passed";` to `return 500 "auth failed";` to simulate authentication 500 error, i get

```
$ curl localhost/test
Auth returned 500
```